# Generating Randomized Start Index for TokenIds in a NFT Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, nft

I've recently started exploring and learning Solidity and have been looking at contracts of some of the famous NFT projects.

One common pattern that I've found is that most of them set a `ProvenanceHash` before mint and *randomize* the `startingTokenIndex` after the mint is complete.

Here's code snippet from one of them

```
function finalizeStartingIndex() public
    {
        require(starting_index == 0, "Starting index already set");
        require(starting_index_block != 0, "Starting index block not set");

        starting_index = uint256(blockhash(starting_index_block)) % max_token_supply;

        if (block.number.sub(starting_index_block) > 255)
        {
            starting_index = uint256(blockhash(block.number-1)) % max_token_supply;
        }

        if (starting_index == 0)
        {
            starting_index = starting_index.add(1);
        }
    }
```

I understand what a **Provenance Hash** is and the **need to randomize** the starting index, but I am having a hard time understanding how this actually works in the contract.

In the above snippet the `starting_index` variable is set, but I could not find its usage anywhere within the contract apart from some guard conditions.

So how does it actually achieve the intended assignment of random tokenIds?

Shouldn't it be used somewhere we actually store/return the ownership or `tokenUri` or something? or am I missing some critical piece of information here?

[Here's the link](https://etherscan.io/address/0x41a70a616a35cbfa00cc0319748f281396366736#code) to complete source code of the contract in question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a redundant piece of code.

From a [BAYC contract analysis blog](https://betterprogramming.pub/bored-ape-yacht-club-smart-contract-breakdown-6c254c774394) -

> BAYC team tried to prevent the sniping of rare tokens during pre-sale by randomizing the order of tokens. startingIndex is supposed to serve as a random offset to randomize the order.
>
> ...
>
> But… this random offset is not actually used anywhere! The code doesn't use it! Despite BAYC’s claims that the order of apes is randomized, it’s actually not! And startingIndex just wastes gas!
>
> The article about BAYC also claims that other NFTs just blindly copy/pasted the BAYC code without understanding what it does. So they inherited this startingIndex bug. I wanted to verify this claim but was too lazy to go beyond an “NFTs inspired by BAYC” google search. If you know of any such contracts, please leave them in the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. I think I kind of knew it, but here I thought since I am new to this whole ecosystem, surely I must be missing some critical piece of information ;) cause  contracts of some of the biggest projects developed by proclaimed developers have this issue.

Comment: [1]
After a little more digging and talking to some other developers I've found out that after generating the starting index, metadata is rotated off-chain in a way that the starting token ids are assigned the metadata from the generated started index.

This works in conjunction with the provenance hash, so it can be proved by calculating the provenance hash taking into account the index offset.

This means it is actually a valid way to do it, if done correctly. Arguably there could have been a better and more elegant way to do it, or at least the whole process should be documented.

Comment: [2]
So, I'll have to remove this as the accepted answer so that it is clear for anyone else landing here in the future.
Thanks.